# displaying values in c structure array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

I'm trying to display the values of my structure array, the compiler throws out the following error:

```
athletes.c:17: error: expected ')' before '*' token
```

Could someone help me out with a solution and if possible an explanation as to what I did wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct athlete {
  char last_name[25];
  char first_name [20];
  int rank;
  float salary;
  };


int main (void) {
    struct athlete players[] = {{"Lebron", "James",1,25}, {"Durant", "Kevin",3,20},{"Duncan","Tim",2,12}};
    display_jock(players);

}

void display_jock(athlete *p) {
    printf ("%10c%10c%10d%10.1f \n", p[0].last_name,p[0].first_name,p[0].rank, p[0].salary);
    printf ("%10c%10c%10d%10.1f \n", p[1].last_name,p[1].first_name,p[1].rank, p[1].salary);
    printf ("%10c%10c%10d%10.1f \n", p[2].last_name,p[2].first_name,p[2].rank, p[2].salary);
}
```

Comment: What is the following error?

Comment: `void display_jock(athlete *p) {` --> `void display_jock(struct athlete *p) {` and put prototype before main.

Comment: `"%10c%10c%10d%10.1f \n"` --> `"%10s %10s%10d%10.1f \n"`

Comment: i get the following error when i implement your fix    athletes.c:17: warning: conflicting types for 'display_jock'
athletes.c:13: note: previous implicit declaration of 'display_jock' was here

Comment: Move `display_jock()` before `main()`.

Comment: `int main (void) {` -->> `void display_jock(struct athlete *p);int main (void) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are several small errors:

- your code does not know the type "athlete", so your class display_jock should be defined with argument struct athlete:  `void display_jock(struct athlete *p)`
- you should forward declare that function: otherwise main doesn't know it (**edit**:you could also just move the `display_jock` function at the top of the main function)
- when printing a char array, you should use `%s` instead of `%c` when using printf.
- your main function should return an `int` (since it is declared as `int main...`)

this is your code fixed up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct athlete {
  char last_name[25];
  char first_name [20];
  int rank;
  float salary;
  };

void display_jock(struct athlete *p);


int main (void) {
    struct athlete players[] = {{"Lebron", "James",1,25}, {"Durant", "Kevin",3,20},{"Duncan","Tim",2,12}};
    display_jock(players);
    return 0;

}

void display_jock(struct athlete *p) {
    printf ("%s%s%10d%10.1f \n", p[0].last_name,p[0].first_name,p[0].rank, p[0].salary);
    printf ("%s%s%10d%10.1f \n", p[1].last_name,p[1].first_name,p[1].rank, p[1].salary);
    printf ("%s%s%10d%10.1f \n", p[2].last_name,p[2].first_name,p[2].rank, p[2].salary);
}
```